# Castle Windsor LifeStyle for WCF?

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, entity-framework, castle

I'm using WCF Facility with entity framework in ASP.NET application.
The goal is to keep dbcontext in IoC container see example:

1)Global.asax

```
    protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Container = new WindsorContainer();
        Container.AddFacility<WcfFacility>();
        Container.Register(
            Component.For<IDBContext>().ImplementedBy<DBContext>().LifeStyle.PerWcfOperation()
            );
    }
```

2)CustomerService.cs
    public class CustomerService : ICustomerService
    {
        private readonly ICustomerBl customerBl;

```
    public CustomerService(ICustomerBl customerBl)
    {
        this.customerBl = customerBl;
    }

    public Customer GetById(int Id)
    {
        Customer customer = customerBl.GetById(5);
        return customer;
    }
}
```

3)CustomerBl.cs

```
public class CustomerBl : ICustomerBl
{
    private ICustomerRepository _repository;
    public CustomerBl(ICustomerRepository customerRepository)
    {
        _repository = customerRepository;
    }

    public Customer GetById(int Id)
    {
        return _repository.GetById(5);
    }
}
```

4)CustomerRepository.cs

```
public class CustomerRepository: ICustomerRepository
{
    public IDBContext _dbContext;

    public CustomerRepository(IDBContext dbContext)
    {
        _dbContext = dbContext;
    }

    public Customer GetById(int Id)
    {
        _dbContext.ContextCounter = 1;
        return new Customer
        {
            Id = 5,
            FirstName = "Joe",
            LastName = "Blogg",
            Age = 45
        };
    }
}
```

5)TestServiceClient

```
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ServiceReference1.CustomerServiceClient customer = new  ServiceReference1.CustomerServiceClient();

        customer.GetById(5);

    }
```

I'm doing following:

1)Call wcf method from CustomerGetById(), dbcontext is instantiated here 
     _dbContext.ContextCounter = 0

2)Call again and has instantiated dbContext - _dbContext.ContextCounter = 1

The goal is to have new instance of dbContextafter each single wcf method call.
How I can achieve this?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you rephrase this: *The problem is that after wcf method call instance of DBContext is saved. I would like to have new instance of DBContext after each single wcf method call. How I can achieve this?* It is really not clear what are you asking for and what behavior do you see now

Comment: I agree with the previous comment. From the way I read your question, it should be doing what you want. PerWcfOperation means the IDBContext instance is scoped to the current WCF request/method.

Comment: For example: 1)Call wcf method CustomerGetById(), dbcontext is instantiated 2)Call wcf method ProductGetById(), now I have the same instance of dbcontext as before. The goal is to have new one.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The following code will register component as **PerWebRequest** life style in WindsorContainer.

```
    public void Register(Component component)
     {
        WindsorContainer container = new WindsorContainer();
        IKernel kernel = container.Kernel;
        kernel.AddComponent(component.Name, component.Service, component.Impl,LifestyleType.PerWebRequest);                                 
     }
```

To make Life style as PerWebRequest you have to add following in Web.config

```
<system.web> 
  <httpModules>
   <add name="PerRequestLifestyle" type="Castle.MicroKernel.Lifestyle.PerWebRequestLifestyleModule, Castle.MicroKernel" />
  </httpModules>
</system.web>

<system.webServer>
 <modules>
  <add name="PerRequestLifestyle" type="Castle.MicroKernel.Lifestyle.PerWebRequestLifestyleModule, Castle.MicroKernel" />
 </modules>
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: I tried to use following:Component.For<IDBContext>().ImplementedBy<DBContext>().LifeStyle.PerWebRequest but it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
 Container.Register(
        Component.For<IDBContext>().ImplementedBy<DBContext>().LifeStyleTransient().AsWcfService()
        );
```

Works for me, but I cant figure out how I tell Windsor to use the Servicebehavior I defined in the Service